# Versioning metadata changes in AEM 6.5

Tags: git, eclipse, metadata, aem, versioning

I'm a newbie to Adobe Experience Manager.

I need to add some metadata to DAM assets. I know I can perform this changes through the Metadata Schema Editor via the UI in AEM's frontend. But how can I store this changes in order to version them in a git repository?
I don't want to manually add the metadata for every environment, I want to deploy/upload my package to do the all the changes. Consider I'm using Eclipse as IDE.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like other types of content, you can serialize this configuration as XML files in a format compatible with [Vault FS](https://jackrabbit.apache.org/filevault/vaultfs.html) and store them in the repository.

The easiest way would be to keep them where they are now and download them through `vault` (or a Maven/Gradle plugin that wraps it). Just ensure the [workspace filters](https://jackrabbit.apache.org/filevault/filter.html) include the right paths.

You'll end up with a set of XML files under `/conf` that contain a bunch of serialized `sling:resourceType="dam/gui/components/admin/schemafield"` nodes. If you don't know where to find them, searching for nodes with this resource type should give you a hint as to their location.

The exact steps may vary depending on the archetype and AEM version you're using.

Comment: Thank you. I actually did the changes via frontend and then exported them via package manager filtering for this path `/conf/global/settings/dam/adminui-extension/metadataschema/my-schema`